# Получить поля объекта json

Tags: javascript, json, frontend

Вывожу в консоль объект:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

могу получить доступ к 4 полям что в фигурных скобках.

Как получить остальные поля? При попытке вывода поля isLoaded - получаю undefined

Пробовал так: Object.keys(jsonObj); Тоже выводит эти 4 поля.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дождаться, когда асинхронный код завершит свою работу, и только после этого получать остальные поля.